# What is wrong with this c++ code using destruction?

Tags: c++, destructor, turbo-c++

```
#include <iostream.h>
class a {
public:
    ~a() { cout << 1; }
};
int main()
{
    a ob;
    ob.~a();
    return 0;
}
```

if wrong than what is wrong with it?
I've tried this code running on turbo c++,still i'm getting the error of

> member identifier expected at "`ob.~a();`"line

else guess the output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Normally should not call the destructor. And TurboC++ is so old and non-standards compliant that it's really no use in asking why it do the things it does.

Comment: It's software literally older than the OP

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>` has also been wrong for the last two decades or so, ever since C++ was standardised. Make it `#include <iostream>` once you have switched to a modern compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't call destructor functions explicitly usually. They will be called implicitly when the instance goes out of scope.

Calling a destructor function for the same instance twice leads to undefined behavior.

---

There's no compiler error with a modern compiler to be observed though. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b6e70450362d81a) please. May be that was one of the rare good decisions from the Turbo C++ designers leaving such in an error message.

---

There are rare cases to call the destructor function explicitly, e.g. if you're maintaining a pool of instances created with [*placement new*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

Comment: Re: "rare good decisions from the Turbo C++ designers" -- huh? Turbo C++ was the leading compiler in its day, widely respected by technical users, and far better at standards conformance and usability than its competitors, most of whom have dropped by the wayside.

Answer (score 2):

The call might work with `ob.a::~a()`.

That being said, you don't need and should not call the destructor explicitly, it is called automatically once the `ob` object goes out of scope.